# ¿Por qué aparece [object Object] al mostrar dato en html?

Tags: javascript

Este es el algoritmo en JavaScript

```js
function repite() {
   
    const arraydos = objAllSheetsInventario.Entradas;
    var repetidos = {};
    let prueba = 0;
    let numeroABuscar = document.getElementById('busca-uno').value.toString().toLowerCase();
    
    numero = arraydos.filter((numero) => {
      if(numero.referencia.toString() === numeroABuscar ){
        repetidos[numero.referencia] = (repetidos[numero.referencia] || 0) + 1;
        prueba = repetidos;
      }  
    });

      const tdtotalCantidad = document.getElementById("tdtotalCantidad");
      tdtotalCantidad.textContent = prueba; 
      console.log(prueba);
  }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
este es lo que me sale en consola.

Cuando lo quiero mostrar por html que uso esta parte del código

```js
const tdtotalCantidad = document.getElementById("tdtotalCantidad");
tdtotalCantidad.textContent = prueba;
```

y lo muestro en el html así

```html
<td id="tdtotalCantidad"> 00</td>
```

me sale este `[object Object]` como se ve en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! prueba = repetidos; prueba es un array, no un numero...

Comment: gracias por tu consejos  
gbianchi
♦ , me podrías ayudar como mostrar ese array en el html por favor muchas gracias   
gbianchi
♦

Comment: En realidad no es un error, estás mostrando el objeto _como tal_. Por cierto, para mencionar a un usuario, usa el @ seguido del nombre de usuario.

Comment: ok muchas gracias lo del @ @gbianchi , y aja si no es un error como tal y pues estoy buscando la formas con solucionar eso , me podrías explicar como solucionarlo por favor ?

Comment: Te sale un objeto porque es un objeto. Necesitas indicarle a html qué atributo de ese objeto quieres pintar, si tienes un objeto `const x = { foo: "bar" }` no puedes usar `div.textContent = x` si no que usarías `div.textContent = x.foo`. EN tu caso lo mismo, pero con el atributo correcto. Si ese atributo es dinámico (viene de la base de datos imagino), debes hacer buscar una manera de obtenerlo. Por ejemplo usando `Object.keys` para obtener sus diferentes atributos, o buscar una mejor manera de devolverlo, eso ya depende de tus necesidades.

Comment: muchas gracias @Benito-B

Answer (score 0):

Tu estas imprimiendo en HTML un objeto, algo como esto:

```js
const UnObjeto = {
  UnaPropiedad : "valorPropiedad",
}
UnDiv.innerHTML = UnObjeto;
```

```html
<div id="UnDiv"></div>
```

Un objeto no cuenta con una representación a modo de `String`, a menos que implemente la función `toString`

```js
const UnObjeto = {
  UnaPropiedad : "valorPropiedad",
  toString(){ return "Representacion en String"}
}
UnDiv.innerHTML = UnObjeto;
```

```html
<div id="UnDiv"></div>
```

---

Básicamente si cambias

```
prueba = repetidos;

//por

prueba = repetidos[numero.referencia];
```

Te va a funcionar, porque ahora `prueba` es un número que es imprimible (ya no es objeto)

Por último estas usando mal la función `filter`, la estas usando como si fuera un `for` a esta función le pasas como argumento otra función (`la condición`), la cual debe retornar `true` o `false`. Esta función te va a retornar todos los elementos que cumplen el criterio de `la condición`

Algo así:

```
function repite() {
   
    const arraydos = objAllSheetsInventario.Entradas;
    let numeroABuscar = document.getElementById('busca-uno').value.toString().toLowerCase();
    
    const repetidos = arraydos.filter((numero) => numero.referencia.toString() === numeroABuscar);

    const tdtotalCantidad = document.getElementById("tdtotalCantidad");
    tdtotalCantidad.textContent = repetidos.length;
}
```